# Como ejecutar dos procesos al mismo tiempo en python

Tags: python, hilos

Se que se puede hacer con multihilos pero no he encontrado la manera de hacerlo

Intengo traerme una base de datos desde un checador, pero como solo se manejan por telnet tengo que recurrir a nc, en una hice un script en bash para correr los comandos en el checador pero del lado del cliente necesito ejecutar otro comando al mismo tiempo para poder traer la db

```
import os
import sqlite3
import threading

class check:

    def __init__(self):
        # os.remove('ZKDB.db')
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.traerDb())
        thread.start()
        os.system('nc 192.168.1.169 6666 > ZKDB.db.bak')
        os.rename('ZKDB.db.bak', 'ZKDB.db')

    def traerDb(self):
        os.system('./downZK.sh')
```

Este es el codigo que he hecho, pero siempre espera a que termine el script y al final el archivo queda en blanco

Comment: TYPO: cambia  a `thread = threading.Thread(target=self.traerDb)`

Comment: Ya lo he hecho y sigue sin traer la info